# Failed to detect schema (Please review and update the file format settings to allow file schema detection)

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm currently trying to import transformed data (csv) from ADLS to Synapse workspace LAKE DATABASE. Then afterwards try to create an external table from data lake. After creating external table name, selecting, linked service and inputting the file it is showing me (Failed to detect schema
Please review and update the file format settings to allow file schema detection) I have been searching high and low with no solution. PLEASE HELP!!!1

I tried with totally new data, resource group, different file and still no success. Still no success. I was following this YouTube tutorial project and learning. I did the part 1 with no problem. The problem starts from part 2 at 8:45 min

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to replicate the issue, I encountered the same error as shown below:

[image]

**I have assigned myself the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the ADLS account as follows:**

Go to Access Control of the ADLS account, click on Add, and select Add Role Assignment as shown below:

[image]

Search for the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role, select it, and click on Next as shown below:

[image]

Select the member and click on Review + Assign as shown below:

[image]

After assigning the role, I tried to create an external table in the lake database. It successfully detected the schema as shown below:

[image]

And created the external table as shown below:

[image]