# Unable to read current version of delta table in azure ml studio using Data asset

Tags: azure, machine-learning, delta, azureml-python-sdk

I am trying to create data assest with ADLS gen 2, and read a delta table on adls gen folder something like this:

```
/
└── my-data
    ├── _delta_log
    ├── part-0000-xxx.parquet
    └── part-0001-xxx.parquet
```

Currently, when creating the data asset I used file dataset type ML v1 APIs, but when reading the table, it shows all the rows(even the deleted ones), and not the most recent version.

I have attempted to create it all the other data asset types for azure Ml v1/v2.
I ideally want to read the most recent version of the delta table and also have the option to change version.

No sucess. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the below code to work, you need to create a mltable(data asset) with correct folder path.

```
import time
   import mltable
   from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
   from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
   current_timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", time.gmtime())
   ml_client = MLClient.from_config(credential=DefaultAzureCredential())
   data_asset = ml_client.data.get("<enter your ml table name>", version="1")
 
   tbl = mltable.from_delta_lake(delta_table_uri=data_asset.path, 
   timestamp_as_of=current_timestamp)
   df = tbl.to_pandas_dataframe()
   df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the procedure below to read the current version of the Delta table:

Add the [Storage Blob Data Contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77147429/failed-to-detect-schema-please-review-and-update-the-file-format-settings-to-al/77155104#77155104) role to your Entra ID, where you created the ML workspace to ADLS account. Run the code below to read the current version of the Delta Lake table:

```
import time
import mltable
current_timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", time.gmtime())
path = "abfss://<containerName>@<storageAccountName>.dfs.core.windows.net/<deltaTablePath>"
tbl = mltable.from_delta_lake(delta_table_uri=path, timestamp_as_of=current_timestamp)
df = tbl.to_pandas_dataframe()
df
```

You will see the Delta table as shown below:

[image]

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-mltable?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli#a-note-on-defining-paths-for-delta-lake-tables).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, good insight. Though I need to view the data using dataset. I have attempted the code from the documentation you share - still not working.

Comment: Could you please provide the error?

Comment: It was a URI path being incorrect. I have used your solution and another to get it working. Thanks for your help